# Places bids on an item with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bids

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bids
end
```

and also a bid model

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

I'm trying to place bids on an item and have bids belong to an item.

This is my item view for show were i'm trying to have a nested form:

```
<%= form_for @item do |i| %>

  <h2>Place a bid</h2>
  <%= i.fields_for :bid do |bid| %>
    <%=bid.label :amount %>
    <%=bid.text_field :amount %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= i.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But its not creating the bid in the database.

This is the permitted params in the items controller:

```
params[:item].permit(:user_id, :title, :bids_attributes => [:amount, :user_id, :item_id])
```

Also my routes:

```
item_bids_path   GET     /items/:item_id/bids(.:format)  bids#index
POST     /items/:item_id/bids(.:format)  bids#create
new_item_bid_path    GET     /items/:item_id/bids/new(.:format)  bids#new
edit_item_bid_path   GET     /items/:item_id/bids/:id/edit(.:format)     bids#edit
item_bid_path    GET     /items/:item_id/bids/:id(.:format)  bids#show
PATCH    /items/:item_id/bids/:id(.:format)  bids#update
PUT  /items/:item_id/bids/:id(.:format)  bids#update
DELETE   /items/:item_id/bids/:id(.:format)  bids#destroy
```

What am I missing??

EDIT (forgot to add my schema):

```
create_table "bids", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your fields_for to:

```
<%= i.fields_for :bid, @bid do |b| %>
```

You can read more here:

[Rails API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

It also looks like you are missing the amount column in your bids table?

Hope that helps....

Make sure you create a bid instance in your item show controller

```
def show
   @bid = Bid.new
   ...
end
```

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately that still wasnt the issue. I have the form in the item show view. I need the form to be a create instead of update.

Comment: point the form manualy then, use `form_for @item, url: bids_path, method: post`

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bids", :id=>"11"} missing required keys: [:item_id]

Comment: updated my answer.. if that doesn't work please add your item show controller code.